# What is the meaning of some phrases used by Dickens?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I cannot interpret the following sentence from Dickens' [*The Haunted House*](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks/fr100113.txt), particularly the bold parts. Can someone help, please?

> If this should **meet the eye of** the gentleman who favoured me with these disclosures, **I trust he will excuse my confessing** that the sight of the rising sun, and the contemplation of the magnificent Order of the vast universe, made me impatient of them.

Comment: Which phrase are you asking about?

Comment: @bib Hopefully that works. It's likely that they are GR, but *impatient* is interesting.

Comment: the bolded words are my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If this should meet the eye of the gentleman* means *If the gentleman happens to read this.*

*I trust he will excuse my confessing* means *I have every confidence that he will forgive mefor confessing.*

Comment: you are right except for the meaning of trust. I have found out Trust has an archaic meaning of hope or expectation according to my oxford concise dictionary. so I'm pretty sure trust here means hope. dont you agree sir?

Comment: Yes, you could say that.